# No connection to the analysis service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, ssas

I can not connect to the analysis service at all. I installed three instance examples of SQL Server on my laptop.

- SQLSERVER2019 Developer Edition
- SQLSERVER2017 Developer Edition
- SQLSERVER2008 R2 Enterprise Edition

The error it gives me says to make sure the browser service is started. But, the analysis service works with browser. How can I solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Is the [SQL Server Browser Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver15) currently running on your SSAS instance's server? You can check this with the [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15) which should be installed on the same server as your instance.

Comment: SQL Server Browser Service No Running . Not in stop mode. Should it be running! I can connect when it is running, but my question is whether the analysis service depends  on SQL Server Browser Service this service.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Microsoft Books Online for the SQL Server Browser service:

> The SQL Server Browser program runs as a Windows service. SQL Server Browser **listens for incoming requests** for Microsoft SQL Server resources and provides information about SQL Server instances installed on the computer. SQL Server Browser contributes to the following actions:
>
> - Browsing a list of available servers.
> - **Connecting to the correct server instance.**
> - Connecting to dedicated administrator connection (DAC) endpoints.

Also:

> For each instance of the Database Engine and **SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS)**, the SQL Server Browser service (sqlbrowser) **provides the instance name** and the version number. SQL Server Browser is installed with SQL Server.

But I think most relevant to your follow up question on if it needs to be running can be found in the [Using SQL Server Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver15#using-sql-server-browser) section:

> If the SQL Server Browser service isn’t running, you are still able to connect to SQL Server **if you provide the correct port number or named pipe**. For instance, you can connect to the default instance of SQL Server with TCP/IP if it’s running on port 1433.

And specifically:

> However, if the SQL Server Browser service isn’t running, the following connections do not work:
>
> - **Any component that tries to connect to a named instance without fully specifying all the parameters (such as the TCP/IP port or named pipe).**
> - Any component that generates or passes server\instance information that could later be used by other components to reconnect.
> - **Connecting to a named instance without providing the port number or pipe.**
> - DAC to a named instance or the default instance if not using TCP/IP port 1433.
> - The OLAP redirector service.
> - Enumerating servers in SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio.

So to summarize my understanding, the SQL Server Browser service doesn't have to be running to be able to connect to SQL Server instances, such as SSAS. **But** if you're trying to connect to a **named instance** (which by your screenshot I think you are) then you need to provide the port number of which that named instance is running on to be able to connect to it.

Otherwise you can keep the SQL Server Browser service running instead and you should be able to directly connect to your named instance.

Comment: Hi, yes, I can connect to service analysis when SQL Server Browser Services  is in start  mode, but you said I should go to the port for the installed version of the service analysis and enter it, correct. I could not find these steps.